# Render menu item children without being 'expanded'?

Tags: theming, 8, navigation

In Drupal 8, how can I render a menu links children without checking 'expanded' on the menu link? I am building a drop down that displays on hover, the links need to render.

My code so far:

```
{% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level) %}
  {% import _self as menus %}
  {% if items %}
    <ul>
    {% for item in items %}
      {% if menu_level == 0 %}
        {%
          set classes = [
            'global-top__utility-item',
            'js-utility-item',
            item.in_active_trail ? 'active-trail',
            item.below ? 'has-submenu'
          ]
        %}
      {% endif %}
      <li{{ item.attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
        {{ link(item.title, item.url) }}
        {% if item.below %}
          {{ menus.menu_links(item.below, attributes, menu_level + 1) }}
        {% endif %}
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

When a parent link has children, they are not rendering unless 'expanded' is checked, which breaks the menu.

Comment: Just load them up and render them I guess, but that's pretty much what the expanded setting does anyway so without changing something else you'll probably end up with the same result. What do you mean by _breaks the menu_?

Comment: The menu stops rendering at the first parent with the child, unless I uncheck show as expanded

Comment: I solved it... Answer to come.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this by adding a macro for children below the main one in my template.

```
{% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level) %}
  {% import _self as menus %}
  {% if items %}
    <ul>
      {% for item in items %}
        {%
          set classes = [
            'global-top__utility-item',
            'js-utility-item',
            item.in_active_trail ? 'active-trail',
            item.below ? 'has-submenu'
          ]
        %}
        <li{{ item.attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
          {% if item.url.options.attributes['data-icon'] is defined and item.url.options.attributes['data-icon'] is not empty %}
            <svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="/themes/custom/pncb/build/img/svg-sprite.svg#{{ item.url.options.attributes['data-icon'] }}"></use></svg>
          {% endif %}

          {{ link(item.title, item.url) }}
          {% if item.below %}
            {{ menus.submenu_links(item.below, attributes, menu_level + 1) }}
          {% endif %}
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}




{% macro submenu_links(items, attributes, menu_level) %}
  {% import _self as menus %}
  <div class="global-top__submenu">
    {% for chunk in items|batch(7) %}
      <ul class="global-top__submenu-col">
        {% for item in chunk %}
          <li{{ item.attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
            {{ link(item.title, item.url) }}
          </li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endmacro %}
```

I split this out due to scoping, different markup for sub menu, and I needed to use the batch filter. Works great.